# Install dist folder created by ng build using msdeploy

Tags: angular, iis, msdeploy

Is there a way to install the output of `ng build --prod` (the dist folder) into IIS using msdeploy?

I'm trying with this command:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Workspace\MyProject\dist.zip  -dest:auto -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="Default Web Site"
```

This fails with:

```
Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb.
Error count: 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it to work with this command, where I just use my `dist` folder:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:iisApp=C:\Path\To\dist -dest:iisApp="Default Web Site/MyApplication"
```